# Monero miner for ppc64le?

Tags: mining, random-x

Is there any Monero miner which supports the current RandomX PoW and compatible with the ppc64le architecture?

I've already checked out [xmr-stak-power](https://github.com/nioroso-x3/xmr-stak-power) and [this port of xmrig for ppc64le](https://github.com/nioroso-x3/xmrig), both of which aren't updated for the current RandomX PoW.

I'm currently running Linux on a ppc64le machine, if that is relevant. A pool miner would be preferable.

Comment: Have you tried the official Monero wallet / daemon?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my question I guess. I was looking for a pool miner. I guess setting up a full node and solo mining will not be feasible for me. Thanks for your suggestion though, I might consider it as an alternative if I can't find anything else.

Comment: Neither of the miner "ports" you linked are going to work for RandomX, they just ported the old CN asm to ppc.